# Terminal services and the browser graphics arcane buttons not rounded

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, dom

In developing software for a company I finally received an image of what my work looks like on their terminals.  The buttons are the old arcane 1995 Windows type.
[image]

Is there a way to force FireFox to use the nice and rounded buttons???  I believe that they have the latest terminal services.

What gives?

TIA

DK

Comment: Can you confirm this only affects Firefox running under Remote Desktop and not when run locally, and not in IE under RDP either? And also that Visual Styles are enabled on the server?

Comment: @Dai No!  I think it is over all the browsers!

Comment: Did you try to change the style of the buttons in CSS?